# UITableViewCell's rectForSection returns estimate when section not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I'm currently trying to add infinite scrolling to a `UITableView`, which contains a number of calendar events. Since the event title doesn't always fit inside a single line I've added a multi-line `UILabel` to the cell. In order to calculate the height of the cell I'm taking advantage of `UITableView`'s new self-sizing cells via Auto Layout in iOS 8. WWDC Session 226 talks about this in more detail.

In order to implement the infinite scrolling mechanism I'm overriding `layoutSubviews` where I need to calculate the height of a section which at the time given ist not visible on screen. This can be done by using `[self rectForSection:0]`. When doing so the table returns a height based on the estimated row size I had to define inside the table's initialiser in order to make self-sizing cells work.

```
self.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
self.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

When the section gets on screen I get the correct size of the section, but since I have to update the table's contentOffset based on the computed height of that specific section this causes my table to jump up and down.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Is there a way to force a section to return the actual height and not the estimated one?

Comment: Don't set the estimated row height.

Comment: @CrimsonChris That doesn't work, estimates are still a multiple of 44.

Comment: Didn't catch that you were using the approach still in beta. If you watch the video again you'll notice that the estimated row height allows the table to wait until the cell is on screen before calculating its height. You will have to calculate the height of your section manually using the old techniques if you need to know the height before it is visible. You can use the same approach that the table view uses if you want. If your cell's use autolayout you could use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:`.